# Mimic UIAlertView Bounce?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

Whats the best way to mimic the bouncing animation from the UIAlertView on the iPhone? Is there some built-in mechanism for this? The UIAlertView itself won't work for my needs.

I looked into animation curves but from what I can tell the only ones they provide are easeIn, easeOut, and linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 animations, one to pop up to very large, and the other one to rescale back to normal size.

(This is the approach use by `UIAlertView` internally.)

Alternatively, you can use the lower-level `CAAnimation` and use `+[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints::::]` to make your own curve.

Answer (score 62):

UIAlertView uses a more sophisticated animation:

- scale to larger than 100%
- scale to smaller than 100%
- scale to 100%

Here's an implementation using a `CAKeyFrameAnimation`:

```
view.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{view.alpha = 1.0;}];

CAKeyframeAnimation *bounceAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
bounceAnimation.values = @[@0.01f, @1.1f, @0.8f, @1.0f];
bounceAnimation.keyTimes = @[@0.0f, @0.5f, @0.75f, @1.0f];
bounceAnimation.duration = 0.4;
[view.layer addAnimation:bounceAnimation forKey:@"bounce"];
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I've been struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 30):

I investigated how animations are added to `UIAlertView`'s layer by swizzling `-[CALayer addAnimation:forKey:]`. Here are the values I got for the scale transform animations it performs:

`0.01f -> 1.10f -> 0.90f -> 1.00f`

with durations

`0.2s, 0.1s, 0.1s`.

All the animations use an ease in/ease out timing function. Here is a `CAKeyframeAnimation` that encapsulates this logic:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *bounceAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
bounceAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
bounceAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
bounceAnimation.duration = 0.4;
bounceAnimation.values = @[
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity]];
bounceAnimation.keyTimes = @[@0.0f, @0.5f, @0.75f, @1.0f];
bounceAnimation.timingFunctions = @[
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut],
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut],
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
```

I believe `UIAlertView` also performs a simple opacity animation from `0.0f` to `1.0f` over the total duration of the transform animation (`0.4`).

Comment: It's up to personal preference. But the key times I provided are exactly what `UIAlertView` is using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it for an app I'm working on.  The effect I was going for was bouncing when you pressed the view.  Experiment with the values to suit your taste and the desired speed of the effect.

```
- (void) bounceView:(UIView*)bouncer
{
    // set duration to whatever you want
    float duration = 1.25;
    // use a consistent frame rate for smooth animation.
    // experiment to your taste
    float numSteps = 15 * duration;

    // scale the image up and down, halving the distance each time
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:duration
                                   delay:0
                                 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubic
                              animations:^{
                                  float minScale = 0.50f; // minimum amount of shrink
                                  float maxScale = 1.75f; // maximum amount of grow
                                  for(int i = 0; i< numSteps*2; i+=2)
                                  {
                                      // bounce down
                                      [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:duration/numSteps * i
                                                              relativeDuration:duration/numSteps
                                                                    animations:^{
                                                                        bouncer.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(minScale, minScale, 1);
                                                                    }];
                                      // bounce up
                                      [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:duration/numSteps * (i+1)
                                                              relativeDuration:duration/numSteps
                                                                    animations:^{
                                                                        bouncer.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(maxScale, maxScale, 1);
                                                                    }];

                                      // cut min scale halfway to identity
                                      minScale = minScale + (1.0f - minScale) / 2.0f;
                                      // cut max scale halfway to identity
                                      maxScale = 1.0f + (maxScale - 1.0f) / 2.0f;
                                  }
                              } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                  // quickly smooth out any rounding errors
                                  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5*duration/numSteps animations:^{
                                      bouncer.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                                  }];
                              }];
}
```