# Change Pin Color when user tapped

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I would change the color from red to green of an annotation when the user pin tapped addition to changing its title and subtitle.

I am truly lost. I searched how to make a custom annotation pin, ok. I found the implementation of the method when the user touches the pin `didSelectAnnotationView` and it works when I tap the annotation `NSLog(@"Tap") ;` , but now I can not change the pin that was touched.

Thank you very much everyone for your contributions.

Ciao

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the pin color, make use of [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) pinColor property.

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init]
pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
```

For custom annotation image, set the image property, as such.

```
UIImage *annImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnnotationIcon.png"];
annView.image = annImage;
```

Do note that the [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKAnnotationView) animateDrop property will not work on custom images. There's a way to duplicate that animation though. See [How do I animate MKAnnotationView drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808876/how-do-i-animate-mkannotationview-drop)

**Update**
So bascially, you do this if you wanna change from red to green upon being selected.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view {
    view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView
            viewForAnnotation:(id)ann {

    NSString *identifier = @"myPin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
    [aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annView == nil) {
        annView= [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:ann
                                               reuseIdentifier:identifier]
               autorelease];
    } else {
        annView.annotation = ann;
    }
// you can define the properties here.

return annView;
}
```

Comment: This is my code, but don't works- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
{
    view.annotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

Comment: Xcode tells me: 
error: Semantic Issue: Property 'pinColor' not found on object of type 'id<MKAnnotation>'

Comment: pinColor is property of MKPinAnnotationView object not MKAnnotationView.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I saw it but I don't know how do it. I'm newbie, and my english is very bad. I have this method declared:
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
{
    NSLog(@"Annotation Tap");
}    
It's Ok, or this?
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view 
{
    NSLog(@"Annotation Tap");    
Sorry,     
Antonio
}

Comment: Sorry again. Now I can see your edited answer. Let me see and I'll tell you something. Ciao. Antonio

Comment: I've create a new project to test your answer, and it works!!!!. Now I'm going to test it in the project that I'm working. Million thanks for your patience and your contributions. Now "Life is beautiful". Ciao. Antonio.

Comment: Ok. It works!!!. Finally, I'm trying to change the title
    viewPin.annotation.title = @"KKKKKKk";
, but I have an error: Semantic Issue: Setter method is needed to assign to object using property assignment syntax. Thanks a lot. Antonio

Comment: Why are you doing "viewPin.annotation.title =@"xxx" " Should be just "view.title =@"xxx" " Make sure you created a MKPinAnnotationView and not MKAnnotationView at viewForAnnotation method like what I posted. It's okay I am a newbie too, just that I had been playing around with mapkit for quite a while. Your english is fine too.

Answer (score 4):

In your method set the `pinColor` property of your `MKAnnotationView` as follows:

```
annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; // Green or Purple
```

Comment: This is my code, but don't works
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
{
    view.annotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

Comment: Xcode tells me: error: Semantic Issue: Property 'pinColor' not found on object of type 'id<MKAnnotation>'

Comment: you have to use the `pinView` on your `MKAnnotationView` - use `view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen`

Comment: Thak You so much for your contibution. Ciao. Antonio

Answer (score 1):

(re) look this :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view {
    view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

}
```

this is a **MKPinAnnotationView** (and not *MKAnnotationView*) in param