# Change pin design

Tags: iphone, ios, mkannotation

Is it possible to change the MKAnnotation pin to a png of my own design?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

override this and be a delegate of MKMapViewDelegate to implement override the method.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
```

Create an annotation,

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];// get a dequeued view for the annotation like a tableview

if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease]; 
    }
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES; // show the grey popup with location etc
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    ///[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    annoationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"random.png"];
```

Custom image done

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the viewForAnnotation delegate callback you can provide whatever view you like.

Answer (score 1):

For custom annotation image, set the image property, as such.

```
UIImage *annImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnnotationIcon.png"];
annView.image = annImage;
```

Do note that the [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKAnnotationView) animateDrop property will not work on custom images. There's a way to duplicate that animation though. See [How do I animate MKAnnotationView drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808876/how-do-i-animate-mkannotationview-drop)