# Multiple pins with multiple colors MKMapView

Tags: iphone, colors, mkmapview, pins

How can I show multiple colors for my pins ?

I have one pin with this function :

```
c1.latitude = 48.7258729;
c1.longitude =  4.5781534;
HistoryMarker* ad15 = [[HistoryMarker alloc] initWithCoordinate:c1 Title:@"Title" SubTitle:@"SubTitle"];

[mapView addAnnotation:ad15];
[ad15 release];"
```

and another one with the user's research

Good night !
(For me, I'm french guy =))

Answer (score 1):

To set the pin color, make use of [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) pinColor property.

For custom annotation image, set the MKAnnotationView image property, as such.

```
UIImage *annImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnnotationIcon.png"];
annView.image = annImage;
```

Do note that the [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKAnnotationView) animateDrop property will not work on custom images. There's a way to duplicate that animation though. See [How do I animate MKAnnotationView drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808876/how-do-i-animate-mkannotationview-drop)

Answer (score 0):

The [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can only be 1 of 3 colours, each with their own guidelines of what they should represent. If you want more, you'll have to implement your own.

**Edit:** To set the pin colour, you need only set the pin colour property:

```
pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can i implement two differents pins ?