# Change speed of animatesDrop for Map Kit Annotations

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpinannotationview

Is it possible to change the **speed** (or **gravity** maybe) for the animation of

`pin.animatesDrop`

Where **pin** is an instance of an `MKPinAnnotationView`

I would really like it if my pins could fall faster.

Comment: I don't think you can change that directly. You can subclass its superclass, MKAnnotationView, and add that behavior. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKAnnotationView

Comment: Agreed. Don't use `animatesDrop`, but animate yourself. I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7045872/1271826) by MrAlek represents a good implementation.