# "Bounce" style animation for UIImageview?

Tags: uiimageview, uialertview, uianimation

I have an image that is the template for a form in my app, I want to add a little bounce effect when its opened, similar to a UIAlertView's when it first shows (zooms in, then 'bounces' then stays still)

Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mimic UIAlertView Bounce?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160150/mimic-uialertview-bounce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already asked. please find it below,

[Mimic UIAlertView Bounce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160150/mimic-uialertview-bounce)

Happy coding!!!

Comment: If its a duplicate, mark it as a duplicate rather tha posting a links to the question in the answer section..

Comment: @Abizern My apologies for that, i didn't know about flagging in Stack Overflow.